# iScroll4 - Click click and drag (HREF)

Tags: javascript, ajax, iscroll4, iscroll

I have a problem in the code, created a carousel with iscroll4, however the image has zoom and click to drag the fancybox event occurs, is there any way to disable the link when dragging?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myScroll;

    function loaded() {
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
            snap: true,
            momentum: false,
            hScrollbar: false,
            onScrollEnd: function () {
                document.querySelector('#indicator > li.active').className = '';
                document.querySelector('#indicator > li:nth-child(' + (this.currPageX+1) + ')').className = 'active';
            }
         });

    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Please indent code to format it: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help